# 100 suggested-edit reviews but no Proofreader badge

Tags: support, badges, review-queues

On the main site, [the suggested-edit review page](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) shows that I have reviewed 104 suggested edits. When I'd reviewed 100, I should have gotten [the Proofreader badge](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/81). I don't have that badge. What gives?

---

Note that [the same question's been asked about Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173439). However, the accepted (and only) answer there is that there were fewer than 100 true suggested edits reviewed and the balance were [audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121) — and (unlike on Stack Overflow) there are no audits on Mi Yodeya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I reached that point with no badge I wondered the same thing and took a closer look.  I suspect that, like me, you've improved some suggested edits during reviews.  The badge description says 100 "approved or rejected" edits; apparently improvements don't count.  Whether that's intended behavior I don't know, but I later got to 100 approvals+rejections and earned the badge.

Comment: Do you *know* your count was 100 approvals+rejections when you got the badge, i.e. that edits don't count, or is that a conjecture/estimate?

Comment: I know that it was 100 when I got the badge, because after I didn't get the badge and developed the theory I made a tally.  The part about improvements is conjecture.

Comment: Ah, then I guess you're right that improvements don't count. Post hoc, ergo propter hoc, right? Have a checkmark.

Comment: Well, we still don't know if that's by design or a bug.  A characterization of the bug isn't the same thing as a resolution. :-)

Comment: Quite right; this question's still tagged [meta-tag:bug] and awaiting a [status-](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/tags) tag.

Comment: I suspect it is only Improvements from before the current review system that count this way, back when improvements used to use [the community user as the owner of the accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80518/improved-edit-suggestions-approved-by-community/80550#comment364859_80550).